# How does python pre-process the script and read files efficiently for fixed subset of large amount of images

Tags: python, performance, file, random

I need to read a subset of files from a large number of files. To read the subset of the files, we will first provide a list of indices to obtain the filenames, and use some python classes to read the subset of files using the filenames.

Let's say we have 15,000 images with the filenames stored in the list `image_filenames`, and we would like to randomly read 100 images using a list of indices `image_indices`.

If we hard-code some random `image_indices` (e.g. `image_indices=[28457, 25862,  9399, ..., 15365]`), it seems that python is able to pre-process the python instructions by obtaining a list of `image_filenames[index]` for all `index` in `image_indices` and seek all the images efficiently with randomly hard-coded indices which takes about 0.5 seconds.

```
image_indices=[28457, 25862,  9399, ..., 15365]
read_image(image_filenames[index]) for index in image_indices # This line takes 0.5 seconds
```

Now we use `numpy.random.choice(15000, 100)` to generate `image_indices`. Then we obtain the subset of filenames using `image_indices`, and read the images using these filenames. This will take about 3 seconds.

```
image_indices=numpy.random.choice(15000, 100)
read_image(image_filenames[index]) for index in image_indices # This line takes 3 seconds
```

Although I just provide a hard-coded indices only (not filenames), is python that clever to pre-process all the instructions I have written and seek all the files efficiently in advance to achieve 0.5 seconds (while it takes 3 seconds for non hard-coded indices)? What is the magic/theory behind?

Is it true that there is a physical limitation (e.g. hard-drive, OS design) that it is impossible to read 100 random images out of 15000 images in 0.5 seconds?

### EDIT

NOTE: The time measure is purely for looping 100 times for the `read_image` function only. It does not count the time taken to construct the indices (such as `numpy.random.choice`)

Comment: Given this information, it should be concluded that it's the creation of the values in `image_indicies` that is responsible for the time sink. Not the actual index lookup. Hard-coding a list using the syntax `[1,2,3....]` is always going to be faster than any other method of making a list. Further, IIRC, when the script is compiled to bytecode, the values in the list can be optimized at compile-time, whereas the dynamically-generated values cannot. Also, IIRC, lists that are not modified are effectively turned into sets at compile-time as well, which can also improve speed.

Comment: To be clear, there is, in no way, an optimization that actually goes and pre-fetches files and reads them or anything of that nature... Python is very much 'what you see is what you get' -- Very few optimizations are performed for you.

Comment: Some optimization ideas: Use generator functions and generator comprehension-instead of normal functions and list comprehension. Use iterators instead of list. Explore python multi-threading if you have supporting hardware resources to reduce processing time. `python` will try to optimize in above conditions by saving on time and space which in-turn improves efficiency.

Comment: @Anil_M I have tried multi-threading `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` and the situation becomes worse (5-7 seconds).

Comment: @sytech The time creation of `image_indices` is not counted and I have added a note. You can try to create 15,000 images (with .tiff extension) and tried to measure the random selection of 100 images. I believe you will be surprised of what I have found!

Comment: If you introduce threading and you get slowdowns, that might indicate you are CPU-bound. You should attach a profiler to the script and see where the time is spent. Try multiprocessing instead.

Comment: I also tried `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` with no avail and obtained similar results (5-7 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the processing time taken to search the filenames with the indices will not change based on whether they are hard coded or not.

The function numpy.random.choice() takes time to generate the random numbers from a uniform distribution.

Go check the source code of the function [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx). This will help you understand the process better.

Also try out different methods to store variables instead of numpy arrays which can help in optimization.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I did not count the time for numpy.random.choice(). Please see my update.